# Resume upgrade to 16.04 - how to resume after starting shell from dialog window

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, resume

When dialog window was displayed to decide what to do with file, i have choosen to "start shell in order to check situation". How i now resume my actualization to 16.04? I am in terminal(bash) now who works normal.

Upgrade from 14.04 LTS by use do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: did you start it in nano or in vim?

Comment: can you post an image? Just click edit on your question and paste an image.

Comment: No, i cannot scroll up to dialog window. Bash works normal, so there are only my tries.

Comment: and what if you just restart the actualization?

Comment: I don't know how, do-release-upgrade returns that there is no newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the command 'exit' into the subshell.

Terminating the subshell will continue the parent installation process.